# How to- Display only certain values in Python

Tags: python, numpy, grouping

I have a dataset the uses pandas and numpy. What I want is to find how many "reports" are within each job title and if possible in largest to lowest there is about 100+ job titles for the sake of this I will use a few as an example.
'
This is what I have :

```
Job_Title     reports
  Tech           0 
  Tech           2
  Sales          1
  Tech           1
  Sales          4
  Sales          0
  HR             0
  HR             1
  Co-op          0
```

What I want:

```
Job_Title       reports
  Sales            5
  Tech             3
  HR               1
  Co-op            0
```

The code I tried was so far:

```
 df.groupby('Job_Title')['reports'].count()
```

I am not sure how to do the sorting just yet.

Comment: use `.sum()` instead of `.count()`? then chain that with `.sort_values(ascending=False)`

Comment: Your title asks "how to display only certain values". The body of your question indicates you want to find the sum of `reports` in each group. Then you mention you're unsure how to sort. Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @QuangHoang count seems to work better but the .sort_values worked thank you

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Sorry I didn't even realize while typing.

Comment: `.count()` will give the number of times they appear, `.sum()` would give you the total of the values. Unless all of your values are `1` you should use `sum()`. In the above example it will give `3 3 2 1` and not `5 3 1 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` instead of `count`:

```
>>> (df.groupby('Job_Title', as_index=False)['reports'].sum()
       .sort_values(by='reports', ascending=False, ignore_index=True))

  Job_Title  reports
0     Sales        5
1      Tech        3
2        HR        1
3     Co-op        0
```